# How to load and save files in Android?

Tags: java, android, file, io

I need to load "configuration" type files for my program in Android, they are both .bin files containing dictionary data for the NLP library. I'm a bit new to Android still, and I'm having trouble finding a folder to place the files in so I can access them when the activity starts.

I also need to create/save/load a filetype specific to my program, and I don't know where to put it either. All I've been able to find on here is people using the getAssetManager() function to fetch input streams, but I explicitly need File objects for me to be able to load them into my pre-existing desktop software code I'd like to reuse (plus the libraries require them anyway)

I've also seen people using a "res/raw" folder, however the ADT did not generate this "raw" file when I made the project - so I'm not sure what to do there either.

Here is how I usually start the software in the desktop version, but I need to fetch these files in an Android environment:

```
    brain.start(new File("memboric.core"), new File("en_pos_maxent.bin"), new File("en_sent.bin"));
    core = brain.getInterpreter().getCore();
```

The memboric.core file can be generated, but I need to know WHERE and HOW to do so.

Thank you very much for your time, feel free to direct me to other resources if you feel this question is inadequate.

TLDR; how do I load "static" files for the software to function (needs to be included with software), and how to create/load/save "personal" files into an appropriate area of the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "raw"-folder you can create it on your own. So check this out, which shows how to handle files in Android: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: no method listed on how to open/load files there on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Context.getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29). Your application can read and write files in that folder and they'll automatically get deleted if your application gets uninstalled.

From that point forward, you can create, delete and read from files like any other Java application.

Comment: No longer applicable?  Context.getFilesDir() doesn't seem to work as code